# Morphia MappingException: Trying to map to an unmapped class

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am new to mongo and Morphia,

I am trying to understand if my issue is a Morphia -> fromDBObject function bug?

object scanning is setup:

```
morphia.mapPackage("com.project.model");
```

I set up a breakpoints on Morphia.java, I can see my object in the Mapped Classes hash map

So this line return true:

```
mapper.isMapped(entityClass)
```

If I evaluate the last line in the function:

```
return (T) mapper.fromDBObject(entityClass, dbObject, cache);
```

It will return the mapped object correctly.

While the fromDBObject function throws an exception (Trying to map to an unmapped class)

```
public <T> T fromDBObject(final Class<T> entityClass, final DBObject dbObject, final EntityCache cache) {
    if (!entityClass.isInterface() && !mapper.isMapped(entityClass)) {
        throw new MappingException("Trying to map to an unmapped class: " + entityClass.getName());
    }
    try {
        return (T) mapper.fromDBObject(entityClass, dbObject, cache);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MappingException("Could not map entity from DBObject", e);
    }
}
```

shouldn't the condition there be:

```
 if (!entityClass.isInterface() || !mapper.isMapped(entityClass))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question - are you talking about two different fromDBObject methods?  The first one you mention is on the mapper, I'm assuming the second one you post the code for is on Morphia?  Secondly, I can't reproduce your failure - is there a simple test case that demonstrates the problem?